# Assign a task to Thread and return from method

Tags: java

```
public class MyThreadExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyThreadExample myThreadExample = new MyThreadExample();
        String country= myThreadExample.getCountry();
        System.out.println(country);
    }
    public String getCountry() {
     /* Question : */
     return "India";
    }
    public void printValues() {

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 200; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Label Question :  I want call printValues() method and immediatly return from this method, can I use **Thread** here to call printValue()

Comment: Using thread doesnt guarantee flow of execution as you expected

Comment: When do you want to call it?

Comment: @immibis .. I want call before the return of getCountry() and execute the printValues() method in background. this is like thread separation.

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* way to run some code in a new thread, assuming you have a Java 8 compiler:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    printValues();
}).start();
```

or assuming you don't have a Java 8 compiler:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        printValues();
    }
}).start();
```

Note, however, that this might not do what you want.

(Some people will recommend using an Executor; when you only have one task to run, there is no difference in behaviour, but the Executor would add more complexity)

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your `printValues()` method this way to start a thread inside the method for the execution of what you want.

```
public void printValues() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 200; ++i) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can surely use **Threads** , I prefer [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) mechanism ,

**Here is how you do it :**

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 200; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    }
});

executorService.shutdown();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ['Futures'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

[See 'Futures and Callables' here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html)